Custom Header Type using Hashes using Faraday
I am using the Faraday gem: https://github.com/lostisland/faraday
I am trying to create a simple custom filter in the request header and can't seem to parse the values correctly:
url = "https://lm-api-reads.fantasy.espn.com/apis/v3/games/flb/seasons/2024/segments/0/leagues/xyz?&view=mScoreboard&view=mScoreboard&matchupPeriodId=2"

response = Faraday.get(url) do |req|
  cookie_hash = {"swid" => "{xyx}", "espn_s2" => "xyz"}
  req.headers['X-Fantasy-Filter'] = {"schedule":{"filterMatchupPeriodIds":{"value":[2]}}}    
  req.headers['Cookie'] = cookie_hash.map { |key, value| "#{key}=#{value}" }.join('; ')
      
  rescue Exception => e
    puts "Failed: #{e}"
  end
end

The problem is the X-Fantasy-Filter I am trying to assign contains both a hash and an array. Any ideas how I can set this properly using Faraday? I have tried encoding the params but it still fails. I have seen ESPN Fantasy API request filtering with X-Fantasy-Filter header but that does seem to help in this case.

Have you tried req.headers['X-Fantasy-Filter'] = {"schedule":{"filterMatchupPeriodIds":{"value":[2]}}}.to_json?

@engineersmnky I have not and that did work. Thank you!
